# Make nginx config like apache2 virtualhosts

Tags: nginx, web-server, virtualhost, configuration

I have web server with apache2 with many subdomains on it like, domain.com, abc.domain.com, def.domain.com etc. etc. Now I got a new nginx server and want to set it up like apache2, so to test I created configs (2 files in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ and link to them from sites-enabled/) as shown,

domain.config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /srv/www/;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name domain.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

abc-domain config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /srv/www/tmp1/;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name abc.domain.com;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

but when I access with domain.com I am getting index.html from /var/www/tmp1 only. Is there something I'm doing wrong in the nginx config?